# Using kwargs with filter_by (Sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

So I'm currently trying to create a dynamic function, that will take 1 kwarg, and use that in it's filter_by.

This is what the function currently looks like:

```
    def Get_from_var(session, **data):
    for entry in data:
        if bool(session.query(Tutor).filter_by(entry=data[entry]).first()):
            return session.query(Tutor).filter_by(entry=data[entry]).first()
        return "No tutor found"
```

I know that my function will only recieve 1 kwarg, so I'm not worried about some weird exceptions. But currently it seems that the 'entry' paramter in both of the filter_by functions, are interpreted literally, and not as variables? Because It tells me that "tutor has no property 'entry'"

This is how I'm currently calling it:

```
tutor = Tutor.Get_from_var(session, tutor_id=filters["id"])
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the `Tutor` model please?  [edit] the question to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `**data` in `filter_by` directly to get the correct result.

```
session.query(Tutor).filter_by(**data).first()
```

** unpacks your data into key-value pairs and passes them to the filter_by function.

*Also, you probably dont want to query twice just to check your if statement.*

Comment: I'm not the one that downvoted it, but it works like a charm! Thank you! Would you know why it didn't work my way? Since it basically is the same?

Comment: Okay, then someone else did it...

I try: 1/2
You can think of **arguments like a dict that gets passed. So your Get_from_var-function receives a variable data = {"tutor_id": filters[id]}.

The you loop over the keys so in the first iteration entry == tutor_id and data[entry] == filters[id]. But when calling filter_by, entry is once again a named parameter, so filter_by actually receives a dict kwargs = {"entry": filters[id]}.

Comment: 2/2

I think whats confusing here is the fact, that you have a parameter named entry that has a value of 'tutor_id' but you are actually not passing this value to filter_by but instead create a new parameter when calling the function.